# Setting JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME path

Tags: java

I have been allocated a Linux box in which has java available

```
# java -version
java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.4.1.el6_3-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

# ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Feb  8  2013 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

I am new to Java and not sure if JRE is installed in ths box but based upon search:

```
# rpm -q jre
package jre is not installed
# find / -iname java -print 2>/dev/null
/usr/lib/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre/bin/java
/usr/bin/java
/usr/share/java
/var/lib/alternatives/java
/etc/alternatives/java
/etc/java
/etc/pki/java
```

But

```
# echo $JAVA_HOME

# echo $JRE_HOME
```

So is JAVA is installed and JRE also - am I correct but what value I should set for JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME env variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly try to get out of root user if possible than after that change below in your `~/.bash_profile`

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/<Java version 7 jdk>; export JAVA_HOME // you can also try JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk 7 version/bin/java
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH
```

save it and then

now `source ~/.bashrc`

after that try

`echo $JAVA_HOME` it will produce the expected result.

Comment: Are my settings now correct:

$echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/
$echo $JRE_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/jre/

Comment: no still its not correct change it to  $JAVA_HOME /usr/java/jdk1.7.0.9.x86_64 than it should work properly

Comment: But : $ls -l /usr/java/jdk1.7.0.9.x86_64
ls: cannot access /usr/java/jdk1.7.0.9.x86_64: No such file or directory
 please confirm?

Comment: @Prakash ok than your previous setting seems correct and you are on right path i guess and JRE home path is not required but still you can do it

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure about any other version of Linux, but in Ubuntu you need open home/.bashrc and add in the end of file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

after that, save file and relogin.

**EDIT**

java will know where is jre by JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 1):

set $JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64

set $JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre

Comment: No trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

JAVA_HOME should be set as parent folder of the java installed path

and JRE_HOME should be /jre

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output you have posted, i can draw the following conclusions:

1. Based on the fact that `java -version` works on your machine, you have the JRE installed.
2. The 'echo' statements do not produce any output as you have not set the environment variables for them.

On a side note, if you are planning on doing Java Development, then you need the **JDK** installed. The JRE comes as a subset of the JDK once installed