# where is define JRE_HOME vaiable System variables or user variables?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I try to start the apache tomcat server but I got error like **JRE_Variable variable is not defined correctly** but I try to define the variable in system variable and user variable but didn`t work it say same error.

And where am i define the variable system variable or user variable?

Comment: Have you tried to modify your .bashrc ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting JAVA\_HOME and JRE\_HOME path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965362/setting-java-home-and-jre-home-path)

Comment: What is the path of your JRE and what have you put in JRE_HOME.

Comment: No, I am not changing it..

Comment: @Matt `.bashrc` if he asks about system or user variable, he is most probably using Windows.

Comment: JRE path is **C:\Program Files\Java\jre7** and I`m put JRE_HOME like **C:\Program Files\Java\jre7;** I refer this [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwisnZKqh-PTAhVKv48KHdEnAKMQFggoMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F28991391%2Fgetting-errorjre-home-variable-is-not-defined-correctly-when-trying-to-run-star&usg=AFQjCNF9unWY50amQpjoGd7nvQf86Txzaw) but there is not mentioned where will put this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you set in system or user properties, they are concatenated before being returned. But if you changed any, you need to log out and log back in or restart. Windows does not apply those changes to already running process and processes they start. So even if you start a new `cmd.exe` from the explorer it might not get the new settings.

If your error message is verbatim, it is not `JRE_HOME` that is missing though, but `JRE_Variable`.

Also double-check that you have set the variable to the correct value, the base path of the Java installation, not the `bin` directory or something like that.